# Reactのrenderで何も表示されない

Tags: reactjs, electron

書籍"Electronではじめるアプリ開発"のchapter4の始めで詰まってしまいました。
(5)表示される画像に(4)で書いているHello, Electron and React JSXが表示されることを期待しているのですが、なぜ出ないか？
どなたか教えてくださいませんか。

(1)entryのindex.js

```
import { app } from "electron";
import createMainWindow from "./createMainWindow";

let mainWindow = null;

app.on("ready", () => {
    mainWindow = createMainWindow();
});

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
    if (process.platform !== "darwin"){
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on("activate", (_e, hasVisibleWindows) =>{
    if (!hasVisibleWindows){
        mainWindow = createMainWindow();
    }
});
```

(2)createMainWindow.js

```
import { BrowserWindow } from "electron";

class MainWindow{
    constructor(){
        this.windows = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
        this.windows.loadURL('file://${__dirname}/../../index.html');
        this.windows.on("closed", ()=>{
            this.windows = null;
        });
    }
}

function createMainWindow(){
    return new MainWindow();
}

export default createMainWindow;
```

(3)loadするhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Markdown Editor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/photon/dist/css/photon.css">
    <style type="text/css">
      #app {
        position: absolute;
        top: 8px;
        bottom: 8px;
        left: 8px;
        right: 8px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="window">
      <div id="app" class="window-content"></div>
    </div>
    <script>require("./dist/renderer/app.js")</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

(4)app.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom"

render(<div>Hello, Electron and React JSX</div>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

(5)表示される画像
[image: 表示される画面]

Comment: (2)createMainWindow.js の `this.windows.loadURL` のところの、シングルクォート ( ' ) をバッククォート ( ` ) にしたらどうでしょうか。[テンプレートリテラル](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)と呼ばれる js の構文です。

Comment: できました。ありがとうございます。
なるほど、こういう書き方があるんですね。(最近JavaScript勉強しだしたので。。。。)

Answer (score 1):

以下の記述のシングルクォートをバッククォートにしないと動かないかと思います！

> ```
> 'file://${__dirname}/../../index.html'
> ```

Comment: すみません！！
コメントを読んでおりませんでした。。。